# Using apache FTPclient to sort and download files using Collections.sort()

Tags: java, file-io, ftp

I am using the apache FTPClient to download files from an FTP site using the following libraries

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPConnectionClosedException;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFileFilter;
```

The files in the FTP folder are in the following format

```
NNNN_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.SSS
```

Examples are provided below:

```
32345_20131224091824445.zip
42345_20131224091824545.zip
12345_20131224091824145.zip
22345_20131224091824345.zip
52345_20131224091824745.zip
62345_20131224091824645.zip
```

What i do at the moment is i list the files in the directory using the listDir() method and add each filename into an ArrayList.

I then sort the ArrayList using Collections.sort(myArrayOfFileNames). This has has far worked for me as it sorts the files by the filenames.

Now i want to sort the files by the timestamp on the filename (not system timestamp). This means i have to somehow strip out everything before and including the _ character before doing the sort.

Given that i need the complete filename to be able to download the file after the sort, i am thinking i should have some kind of key, value map where i would store the full name as the key and the stripped out value as the 'value' in the map then sort the values. My map would look something like this

```
key                         value
32345_20131224091824445.zip 20131224091824445.zip
42345_20131224091824545.zip 20131224091824545.zip
12345_20131224091824145.zip 20131224091824145.zip
22345_20131224091824345.zip 20131224091824345.zip
52345_20131224091824745.zip 20131224091824745.zip
62345_20131224091824645.zip 20131224091824645.zip
```

The above solution would probably work but is there a quicker or cleaner solution because i feel the above solution is probably not the best.

Comment: I am trying to understand why would you need a hashmap for this. if stripping down the digits is the only issue, how hard would it be to strip those digits (before _) and then store them in arraylist.

Comment: Because i need to know what the original filename was to be able to download the file. To download the filename i have to provide the complete name.

Comment: I have to get the list of filenames, sort them and then download the files in the correct order using the sorted list. During the download i can only specify the correct full filename not the one with the stripped digit hence i have to store both in the map.

Comment: are these digits before '_' always unique?

Comment: Yes the digits are always unique

Comment: ok I gave it a thought, if I were you I'd probably end up doing the same thing. you could store the return value of compareTo() in a different arraylist but in the end you also want to be able to download the files on first come first serve basis, so for that you would need a mapping which can only be provided by a key-value pair. you could also look at this. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your custom comparator and sort list of your files. It shall be easy to implement this comparator, just substring the filenames and compare them.

```
List<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();
files.add("42345_20131224091824545.zip");
files.add("12345_20131224091824145.zip");

Collections.sort(files, new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        String s1 = o1.substring(6, 21);
        String s2 = o1.substring(6, 21);
        return s1.compareTo(s2);
    }
});
```

PS. Your list will still hold your original objects, so you do not need any map to have both original and stripped file name. This is internal detail of the comparator.

Comment: This looks interesting. I will try it but if you can show me an example that would be very useful.

Comment: well, I have to upgrade IDE, meanwhile I will try to code it without code completion and compiling :-)